# How do you split duplicate letters with "x" in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function which is able to detect when two letters back to back are duplicates, for example the ls in "hello", and split the duplicate letters with the letter "x". Here is my code:

```py
plaintext = input("Enter plaintext here: ")

plaintext = plaintext.lower() # makes plaintext lowercase
plaintext = plaintext.replace(" ", "") # removes all spaces

# this separates all duplicate letters

i = 0 # sets i to 0
for letter in plaintext:
    if plaintext[-1] == plaintext[-2]: # if the last letter is the same as the second to last
        plaintext = plaintext[:-1] + "x" + plaintext[-1:] # separate them with an x
    elif plaintext[i] == plaintext [i+1]: # if one letter is the same as the next letter
        # the line above makes an error
        plaintext = plaintext[:i+1] + "x" + plaintext[i+1:] #separate them with an x
        i += 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

This code works when I enter `hello there` as the input; I receive `helxlothere`. However, when I test another input, such as `heythere`, `IndexError: string index out of range` shows up for `elif` line (line 12). How can I make this code work for all inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IndexError` is caused by the fact that you are looking at `plaintext[i+1]`. As you can see in the word `heythere`, there are no letters which match back to back, and therefore the code continues until it hits the end, and so you get an `IndexError` because there is no element `i+1`.

You can fix this by using this code instead:

```
plaintext = input("Enter plaintext here: ")

    plaintext = plaintext.lower() # makes plaintext lowercase
    plaintext = plaintext.replace(" ", "") # removes all spaces

    # this separates all duplicate letters

    i = 0 # sets i to 0
    for letter in plaintext:
        if plaintext[-1] == plaintext[-2]: # if the last letter is the same as the second to last
            plaintext = plaintext[:-1] + "x" + plaintext[-1:] # separate them with an x
        try:
            elif plaintext[i] == plaintext [i+1]: # if one letter is the same as the next letter
                # the line above makes an error
                plaintext = plaintext[:i+1] + "x" + plaintext[i+1:] #separate them with an x
                i += 1
            else:
                i += 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

This code should stop your code from crashing in the `elif` statement, while also completing properly.
Hope this helps, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to achieve this.
For both approaches, it will work for `hello there` `hey there`
The difference comes when more than two character repetition happens.

#### approach 1

```py
import re
string='hello there'
# find Any repeated character and add x in between them
answer = re.sub(r'(.)\1{1}', r'\1x\1', string)
print(answer)
```

Here for `hellllo there` text, you will get output `helxllxlo there`

#### approach 2

alternatively, you can use this method.

```py
s="hello there"

for match in re.finditer(r"(.)\1+", s):
    old=s[match.start():match.end()]
    s=s.replace(old,'x'.join(old))
print(s)
```

here for `hellllo there` text, you will get output `helxlxlxlo there` as output.

I think the second approach will be more appropriate.

Comment: fails for `helllllo there`

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving the IndexError because during iterating, when the loop reaches the last letter,
`elif plaintext[i] == plaintext [i+1]:`
this line checks for the letter after the last letter, which does not exist, which causes the program to run into IndexError.

You have to check till the second last letter, for it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and easier way to arrive at the same output with a bit easier logic.

***Logic***

Create a new string and insert all letters which are in the old string, `plaintext`, to the new string, `newPlainText`, and check only for one condition that is whether the last letter is same as current or not and if yes then also insert letter `'x'` into the `newPlainText` and that's it!

```py
plaintext = input("Enter plaintext here: ")

plaintext = plaintext.lower() # makes plaintext lowercase
plaintext = plaintext.replace(" ", "") # removes all spaces

# this separates all duplicate letters

newPlainText = plaintext[0] # copy the first letter of plaintext to the new string which will handle the duplicates and insert `x` between them

i = 1 # sets i to 1

while i < len(plaintext):
    if plaintext[i] == plaintext[i-1]: # we check that if prev and current letters are same then also append x to the new string
        newPlainText += "x"
    
    newPlainText += plaintext[i]    # we insert the required current letter to the new string in each iteration
    i += 1

print(newPlainText)
```